# How can I avoid Outlook adding "on behalf of" on my outgoing emails?

Tags: outlook.com

I have 2-3 different email accounts, and I would like to manage them within a single interface (without a desktop app).

With my main email (Hotmail) I have defined the other 2 emails, the problem is when I reply an email of a secondary account Outlook adds

> *Reply of* `secondary email` *on behalf of* `main email`

Is there any way to hide the `main email` replying with Outlook?

Answer (score 1):

[A similar question was posted in 2012 on the Microsoft Forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/mail-email/remove-sent-on-behalf-of-outlookcom/9e9a7b48-37ce-4d2e-9d60-b1e35f29a95a).

However, since then, this issue has been resolved. Follow these steps:

1. In Outlook.com: Go to *Settings* (top right) → *More mail settings*. Under the *Managing your account* section, click on *Your email accounts*.
   [image: 'Add a send-and-receive account' button from outlook.com]
2. Go through the process to add this new email account. To be on the safe side, you may first want to unlink the already linked account (i.e. the secondary email).
3. Now, when you try and compose an email, on the top left, you will be able to pick the *From* address.
   [image: Outlook.com's compose email window]